# Rails: Ways to do basic email verifcation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have an app that uses Devise to do account creation, etc.

But I have another portion of the app that requires just basic email verification not associated with accounts. Is there an easy way to use Devise for that, or is there a better approach? I just want a link sent to the email address entered, that when clicked, marks the address as verified in the database. I'm oddly not having much look coming up with solutions in my searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit roundabout, but the answer to this problem lies in the [beta invites](http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations) railscast. Ryan Bates walks through how to create a beta invite link, email it out to a user, and verify an account once the user clicks that link.

I'm actually going to be spending today implementing a project invitation system using this method, which should be very similar to the technique showed here.

Comment: Actually, this is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously feel the given solution is overkill. Since you mentioned you already use Devise, you can use Devise JUST for email confirmation as well.